# SQL command to return another row from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server to store stock and derivatives on the same table.

Each entry/row has this format:
ric, inst, price, ttime, strike (and others)

ric is the code for stock and derivatives (which are different even if they refer to the same stock)

inst is 0 for stock, 1 for call option and 2 for put option

strike is the strike price for the option ( it is assumed 0 for stocks)

price is the last traded price of the stock/option and ttime is the transaction time.

[image]

I want to make a query for this result:

```
stockric | sttime | sprice | cric | cttime | cprice
```

where stockric = ric, sttime = ttime, sprice = price for all rows which have inst = 0 (i.e. the first 3 columns are for stock information)

For each of stock information, I want to get the corresponding information (ric, ttime, price) for a call option from the same table, let's call them (cric, cttime, cprice)

The conditions for cric, cttime, and cprice are:

1.The row must have inst = 1 (identifier for call option), and cttime must be before sttime

2. the RIC code must match a certain criterion
3. the call option with a strike closest to the stock price is preferred, then the most recent trade is preferred

In short, get the last traded price of an at-the-money call option

Adapting the solution from Mr. Gordon Linoff, I was able to get this code working

```
SELECT TOP (5) sp.ric as stockric, sp.ttime as sttime, sp.price as sprice, 
                sp2.ric as cric,sp2.strike as strikeverification, sp2.ttime as cttime, sp2.price as cprice
FROM [dbo].[swirepacific] sp CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) sp2.*
      FROM [dbo].[swirepacific] sp2
      WHERE sp2.inst = 1 and sp2.ttime <= sp.ttime and sp2.ric like substring(sp.ric,1,4) + '%'
      ORDER BY ABS(sp2.strike - sp.price), sp2.ttime desc
     ) sp2
WHERE sp.inst = 0
```

However, a worrying aspect of this is the slow speed.  Getting the top 5 results took 16 seconds to run for a ~900,000 rows x 8 columns table on a 16c / 96gb ram threadripper system.  Is the above code correct and is there any room for performance improvement?

[image]

Comment: You do mean you want to create a resultset, not a table right? A table would be storing the new information in a new table in the database? A resultset is the result of a query.

Comment: I have not thought of this issue yet.  I only need the result once for processing in F#/python and then it can be discarded.  I imagine a resultset is more suitable?  I will edit my question for clarity thanks

Comment: You can only return one value from your nested query (scalar subquery). You will have to construct a query for each value you need.

Comment: Well since we don't have any test data or DDL to use to test with or know exactly what the result should look like, I am going suggest you might just want to move that SELECT statement down to a CROSS APPLY and see if that gives you what you want. That appears to be what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are hard to follow.  This just isn't clear:

> (cric, cttime, cprice) = (ric, ttime, price) from a row where inst = 1, strike = closest to sprice, use the one below sprice for tie-breaking, cttime immediately before sttime

If I interpret this as you want the closest strike price, then one method is `apply`:

```
SELECT sp.ric as stockric, sp.ttime as sttime, sp.price as sprice,
       sp2.*
FROM [dbo].[swirepacific] sp CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) sp2.*
      FROM [dbo].[swirepacific] sp
      WHERE sp2.stockric = sp.stockric AND
            sp2.inst = 1 
      ORDER BY ABS(sp2.strike - sp.price)
     ) sp2
WHERE inst = 0
```